# How to find which checkboxes are selected and pass them to ActionResult in MVC?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I have a MVC5 app, and in one of my views, I have something like that:

```
<div id="subcatsform" class="form-group" style="visibility:hidden;">
     @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Subcategories, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
     <div id="subcats" class="col-md-9">

      </div>
</div>
```

Then, in my JavaScript part, I do something like this in order to populate my empty `div`.

```
$(function () {

    $("#CategoryID").on("change", function () {
        var selected_option = $("#CategoryID option").filter(":selected").text();
        $("#subcats").empty();

        if (selected_option != "Please select a category") {
            $("#subcatsform").css("visibility", "visible");

            $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/GetSubcategories",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    cid: $("#CategoryID").val(),
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                        var checkbox = '<input type="checkbox" name="subcategory" value="' + value.id + '"> ' + value.value + '<br />';
                        $("#subcats").append(checkbox);
                    }); 
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            $("#subcatsform").css("visibility", "hidden");
        }
    });

});
```

So, I simply check with category is previously selected, and then accordingly list all the subcategories found inside that category, and create input with type checkbox for each one of them. This works all fine, I'm able to get the appropriate subcategories when I change my category, and it creates the checkboxes for me.

The problem is that, later I don't know how to find out which checkboxes are selected, when the user presses the submit button in my view's form.

My `ActionResult` is defined like this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> RegisterBusiness(BusinessViewModel model)
```

And inside my BusinessViewModel, I have a property defined like this:

```
public virtual ICollection<Subcategory> Subcategories { get; set; }
```

Any idea, how can I get the all checked checkboxes, and get their value property when the form is submitted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have a boolean property named IsSelected in your SubCatagory class. 
You should be to able send the values like this

```
 var checkedList = $.map($(':input[name="Subcategory"]'),
   function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    return {
       name :$this.data('subcatagory'), // You can add the subcatagory as a data dash attribute or any other unique identifier in  html of the checkbox before appending
       IsSelected  : $this.is(':checked')
        }});
        $.ajax({
          url : '<your url>',
          type:"POST",
          contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
          data : JSON.Stringify({
                  'Subcategories' :checkedList
                 })
        });
```

Comment: And how will I know which one(s) are checked by the user? I see in your example, you manually list which checkboxes are selected.

Comment: Thanks for the update, so for the `<your url>` part, I should put Account/RegisterBusiness, which is the action method where I want to manipulate the selected subcategories? Can you also give me the code that I need to have inside my ActionResult?